# Filter criteria with entity reference field doesn't work

Tags: entities, views

I have a field called event_author, which is a entity reference to user. These are the settings for the view.

> [image]

They produce the following output.

> [image]

After I add the filter, there is no result anymore. It seems the entity reference is not matching up with *author1*.

> [image]

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 0):

I hover over the field. It `says event_author_id`. It should be the id of the author, instead of text. Or If I want to use text 'author1' in filter. I need to add a relationship in the view. Like a mysql join.